# ASP.NET Core 2.0 with Angular JS rendered HTML code found messed

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-core

I was playing around with ASP.NET core 2.0 SPA with Angular 4 using Visual Studio 2017 Community Edition. Running the sample application I found the HTML code was messed, the tags were not aligned properly and are duplicated. Any clues anyone please?

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<app><html>

</app></body></html>
</app>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove all inner tags into `html` including `html` itself.

Comment: Can you add the code that generated this `html` to the question?